# DummyVecEnv with easyrl : AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I'm creating a PPO agent for Texas hold'em (Poker), here is how I initiate my agent:

```
    def initiate_agent(self, env):
        self.envwrapped = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
        ob_size = env.observation_space[0]
        
        actor_body = MLP(input_size=ob_size,
                        hidden_sizes=[256] * 3,
                        output_size=256,
                        hidden_act=nn.Tanh,
                        output_act=nn.Tanh).to(self.device)

        critic_body = MLP(input_size=ob_size,
                        hidden_sizes=[256] * 3,
                        output_size=256,
                        hidden_act=nn.Tanh,
                        output_act=nn.Tanh).to(self.device)


        if isinstance(env.action_space, gym.spaces.Discrete):
            act_size = env.action_space.n
            self.actor = CategoricalPolicy(actor_body,in_features=256,action_dim=act_size)

        elif isinstance(env.action_space, gym.spaces.Box):
            act_size = env.action_space.shape[0]
            self.actor = DiagGaussianPolicy(actor_body,in_features=256,
                                            action_dim=act_size, 
                                            tanh_on_dist=cfg.alg.tanh_on_dist,
                                            std_cond_in=cfg.alg.std_cond_in)

        else:
            raise TypeError(f'Unknown action space type: {env.action_space}')

        
        self.critic = ValueNet(critic_body, in_features=256)
        self.agent = PPOAgent(actor=self.actor, critic=self.critic, env=self.envwrapped)
```

However, I receive error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 394, in <module>
    command_line_parser()
  File "main.py", line 129, in command_line_parser
    runner.ppo_train(model_name, random = random)
  File "main.py", line 286, in ppo_train
    ppoAgent.initiate_agent(env)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\neuron_poker\agents\agent_ppo.py", line 63, in initiate_agent
    self.envwrapped = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\neuron_poker\lib\site-packages\easyrl\envs\dummy_vec_env.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.keys, shapes, dtypes = obs_space_info(obs_space)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\neuron_poker\lib\site-packages\easyrl\utils\vec_env_util.py", line 50, in obs_space_info
    shapes[key] = box.shape
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

It seems the problem is `self.envwrapped = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])`, but i can't find any solution online. Any solutions? Really appreciate any feedback!!!